# python Faster way to write each dict value to a different file

Tags: python

I have a dict where each value is a pdf file and I would like to write each value of the the dict to a different file. The only way I have found is the following

```
apple = {
   'a': "first pdf",
   'b': "second pdf"
 }

for key,values in apple.items():
    filename = "output/%s.pdf" % (key)
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
     f.write(values)
```

Do you have another way that might speed up the process?

Comment: Is that code really working out for you?  When you iterate through a dictionary, you get the keys, not keys and values.  Perhaps you meant `for key,values in apple.items()`?

Comment: The code as you've posted it does not even run, though (`for x in dict` iterates over the keys, not the items, and you can't write non-`bytes` objects to files). If you have a performance problem, are you really sure it is related to this particular structure? Assuming these problems were fixed, it's pretty much as fast as it could be.

Comment: Alright...what makes you think it's slow?...and besides as mentioned in previous comments, I don't think either that code is working properly as you are only iterating through dict's keys...

Comment: Your code looks simple and straightforward, also fast enough in my option.

Comment: @zondo thanks I've corrected the typo

Comment: Well, I must agree with everybody else: that's the fastest it gets.  If it's too slow, you'll have to deal with it or use a different language.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty simple and straightforward, and I would probably use it unless there is a huge amount of files involved, in which case I would use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) (due to the fact it's IO bound) as so:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
apple = {
   'a': b"first pdf",
   'b': b"second pdf"
 }

def write_to_file(file_pair):
    name, data = file_pair
    filename = "output/%s.pdf" % (name)
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)

# Set max_workers to the number of threads you wish to use (4 is good)
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    res = executor.map(write_to_file, apple.items())
```